# What file should I hand in after detaching database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on a database project using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, and I have to hand in the project tomorrow.

I only have a simple question:

- After detaching the database, I just have to hand in the (`.mdf`) file?
- Can the instructor open the database using only this file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The `.MDF` should be fine because the attach procedure will build a log if necessary. However, it's possible you might just give him a `.BAK` (full backup).

[Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) that will walk you through building a backup.

Answer (score 4):

To make it easiest on the instructor, I would provide a .BAK file. This is going to be easiest for him or her to restore (and minimizes the risk of something happening to the .mdf file while it is detached, while in transit, etc. - you now have zero copies of your database).

If your instructor explicitly asked you to *detach* the database, then I would provide both the .mdf file and the .ldf file. Yes, they can attach the .mdf file without the .ldf file, but I suspect they would have to look up the syntax to do so.

In fact it wouldn't hurt to backup the database, then detach it, and send them a zip file containing the .bak, .mdf and .ldf files. This will take a few extra minutes on your part, but will completely eliminate the need for the instructor to come back to you in case you guess wrong (or we guess wrong - we don't know your instructor's requirements any better than you do).

Answer (score 1):

Use .bak file

The full back up contains all the information necessary to restore the entire database, mdf, ldf, and ndf files

Answer (score 0):

.mdf file is all what you need. 
When you want to create new db from mdf file just click on Attach option and select your mdf file.
Yes, Michael you are right but backup is copy of database (including data), not only a structure.

Comment: Do you think detaching a database doesn't include data?

Comment: No, backup is more than .mdf because backup contains .mdf